# Question about Spurious Relationships of Trending Variables

Tags: regression, time-series, spurious-correlation

Why is the answer to this question 'false?'

> If both X and Y exhibit trending behavior, then regression of Y on X and a trend variable will always generate spurious relationship.

What are some cases in which this might be false? Or why is it false in general? I can think of a few true instances...